# Target specific folder with Gatsby and allImageSharp context

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

I'm a beginner on Gatsby. I try to display a batch of images in grid from a specific folder. I find a script to do that, but that's catch all pics from my `data` folder and my purpose is target a specific one. I try a script but that's don't work with `allImageSharp` when I try to filter this one `allImageSharp(filter: { sourceInstanceName: { eq: "media" } }) {`.
When I try `allImageSharp(filter: { id: { regex: "/media/" } }) {` just display a blank window, but that's work fine like that `allImageSharp {`

`javascript`

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Img from "gatsby-image"
import Layout from "../components/layout"

const img_grid_style = {
  display: "grid",
  gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(auto-fill, 200px)`,
}

export default ({ data }) => (
  <div>
    <Layout title="IMAGE GRID"></Layout>
    <div style={img_grid_style}>
      {data.allImageSharp.edges.map(edge => (
        <Img fluid={edge.node.fluid} />
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
)



export const query = graphql`
  query {
    allImageSharp(filter: { sourceInstanceName: { eq: "media" } }) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          fluid(maxWidth: 200, maxHeight: 200) {
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

`config`

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
      options: {
        // Available options and their defaults:
        base64Width: 20,
        // forceBase64Format: ``, // valid formats: png,jpg,webp // don't work on OSX
        useMozJpeg: process.env.GATSBY_JPEG_ENCODER === `MOZJPEG`,
        stripMetadata: true,
        defaultQuality: 50,
        failOnError: true,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `media`,
        path: `./media/`,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your path in your `gatsby-source-filesystem` to:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: `media`,
    path: `${__dirname}/media/`,

  },
},
```

The snippet above will match. `rootOfYourProject/media`, change it to your media path keeping the `${__dirname}`.

Now, your filesystem can be filtered by `media` (without slashes).

```
export const query = graphql`
  {
    allFile(filter: {sourceInstanceName: {eq: "media"}}) {
      nodes {
        childImageSharp {
          fluid {
            base64
            tracedSVG
            srcWebp
            srcSetWebp
            originalImg
            originalName
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Since you can't use fragments in the GraphQL playground (`localhost:8000/___graphql`) I've used the extended version, however, you should use the `...GatsbyImageSharpFluid` once applied to your code.

`allFile` or `allImageSharp` should do the trick.

---

I've fixed your project in [this PR](https://github.com/StanLepunK/gatsby_react_lab/pull/1). The query was retrieving properly the results, however, you were missing some nested objects to get the final fluid image:

```
export default ({ data }) => {
  return <div>
    <Layout title="IMAGE GRID FROM SPECIFIC FOLDER"></Layout>
    <div style={img_grid_style}>
      {data.allFile.edges.map(({ node }) => (
        <Img fluid={node.childImageSharp.fluid} />
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: Thx for your return but there is problem fluid don't work with file the terminal retrun `42:11  error  Cannot query field "fluid" on type "File". Did you mean "uid"?  graphql/template-strings`

Comment: when I try with `allImageSharp`the terminal return `39:29  error  Field "sourceInstanceName" is not defined by type ImageSharpFilterInput  graphql/template-strings`

Comment: The updated snippet is working on my local machine.

Comment: The code don't return error, but nothing is displaying. The code used to display : ```export default ({ data }) => (
  <div>
    <Layout title="IMAGE GRID FROM SPECIFIC FOLDER"></Layout>
    <div style={img_grid_style}>
      {data.allFile.nodes.map(node => (
        <Img fluid={node.fluid} />
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
)```

Comment: Try to debug your `allFile` object to check where's the missing value.

Comment: Shame on me, I don't know how to debug. I'm novice on the web. I don't how use debogueur on Mozilla. Just in case my code is here https://github.com/StanLepunK/gatsby_react_lab

Comment: Check the pull request: https://github.com/StanLepunK/gatsby_react_lab/pull/1 It's fixed :)